# Mock FileInputStream() with Spock

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spock

I have the following method which I need to write unit tests with Spock.

```
  private Credentials getCredentials() throws IOException {
    return GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(gcpKey));
  }
```

I was unable to mock "new FileInputStream(gcpKey)" part.

what I tried so far is below.
1.

```
given: "mock service"

        InputStream inputStream = Mock(InputStream.class)
        
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = Stub(FileInputStream.class){
            new FileInputStream(_) >> inputStream
        }
```

2. 

given: "mock service"

```
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = GroovySpy(name : "name")
        1 * new FileInputStream("name")
```

Any one have idea regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Make the input stream injectable, then you can easily pass in a mock. Do not create your method's dependencies inside the method. It makes your code untestable without additional tools like Sarek, Mockito or the outdated PowerMock. If you need such tools, it is usually a sign that you should refactor your code. TDD is a design tool rather than just a means to cover your code with tests. You may want to search the WWW for terms like "dependency injection" or "inversion of control".